# Layover Norwegian Air Shuttle

Tags: layovers

LAX to FCO via LGW. Believe it's a 4hr LO, does Norwegian allow 24hr LO? until the next day?

Comment: What do you mean, by "does Norwegian allow"? Are you asking whether you can get Norwegian to sell you a ticket for the same combined price where you have a stopover until the next day instead of the 4 hour layover of the connection you have found now?

Answer (score 5):

[Can I make a booking with a stopover?](http://norwegian.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1220/~/can-i-make-a-booking-with-a-stopover%3F)

> Sorry, we do not offer stopover or multi-leg tickets, and it is only possible to order direct and connecting flights at [norwegian.com](https://www.norwegian.com).

Answer (score 0):

At least not if you book the trip online on one ticket. You might get it by calling their booking office, but must then in any case pay additional fees for booking by phone.

Since Norwegian Airlines simply add up the ticket prices when selling multi-leg flights, booking LAX-LGW-FCO will cost the same as booking LAX-LGW and LGW-FCO separately, it might be an option for you to simply book two separate tickets. In that case, you must however be aware, that the transfer is not guaranteed and that the ticket for the second leg will be void if the first flight is delayed so much, that you can't catch the second flight.

Comment: @pnuts No, of course not. I added some clarification to my answer if that was not obvious.